# Customize GrayLog2 GELF View

Tags: graylog2

GrayLog2 streams show by default: Date, Host, Severity, Facility and so on. 
I'd like to remove the redundant fields (Host, Severity and Facility).

Is it possible to customize this view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is customizable by editing the file _table.html.erb

the file is located in /data/servers/equinox_logs-apache/log_ui/app/views/messages

you can comment out the undesired columns in the html.